# How to send my input with mail in PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 problems:

1. He doensn't send the name that I put into the form.
2. He only sends the last thing that I have put in as product and the amount.

e.g.: If I put in `Naam: TOM, Productnaam: Zwart 26, aantal: 4`, then I click `toevoegen`, it appears. Then I put in `Naam: TOM, Productnaam: Zwart 11 , aantal : 5`, and click `toevoegen` again, it appears beneath the other order. Then when I send it , everything goes well but when I see my mail this is what I get :

`Naam: 5 x Zwart 11`

Any help with these problems?

```
 <?php
    include "authenticatie1_p88";
    ?>
    <?php

    ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.olvgroeninge.be");
    ini_set("smtp_port", 25);
    ini_set ("sendmail_from", "johan.dejonckheere@sintamandscollege.be");
    session_start();

    // Toevoegen
    if( isset( $_GET['ADD'] ) && ereg('^[1-9][0-9]*$', $_GET['aantal'])) {
    $_SESSION['winkelwagen'][$_GET['ID']] = $_GET['aantal'];}

    // Verwijderen
    if( isset( $_GET['DEL'] ) ) {
    unset($_SESSION['winkelwagen'][$_GET['ID']]);}

    // Alles verwijderen
    if( isset( $_GET['EMP'] ) ) {
    unset($_SESSION['winkelwagen']);}

    // Laat lijst zien
    if( isset( $_SESSION['winkelwagen'] ) ) {
    foreach ( $_SESSION['winkelwagen'] as $key=>$val ) {
    echo "$val x $key<br>";}}

    //Verzend de bestelling naar het emailadres
    if( isset( $_GET['VER'] ) ) {
    $boodschap2 = print_r( $key, true );
    $boodschap = "Naam: ".$_GET["naam"]."$val x $key";
        mail("nielbutaye@gmail.com","Uw inkt bestelling", $boodschap);
        echo "Uw gegevens zijn verstuurd";}
    ?>
    <form><table width="200" border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="images/hewlett-packard-51626ae-hp-26-hp51626a.jpg" width="350" height="350" /></td>
        <td><img src="images/hewlett-packard-c4810a-hp-11-hpc4810a.jpg" width="350" height="350" /></td>
        <td><img src="images/intktpatroona.jpg" width="400" height="400" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Product: Zwart 26</td>
        <td>Product: Zwart 11</td>
        <td>Product: Gekleurd 57</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

      <p>Naam: 
      <input type="text" name="naam" value="<?php echo $_POST["naam"] ?>"><br>
        Product:
      <input type="text" name="ID"><br>
        Aantal:
      <input type="text" name="aantal"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="ADD" value="Toevoegen">
      <input type="submit" name="DEL" value="Verwijderen">
      <input type="submit" name="EMP" value="Legen">
      <input type="submit" name="VER" value="Verzenden">
      </p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `$val` and `$key` in your mail-sending part suggests that you think you are still inside a `foreach` loop, which is not the case. Try replacing with this:

```
//Verzend de bestelling naar het emailadres
if( isset( $_GET['VER'] ) ) {

    $boodschap2 = '';
    foreach ( $_SESSION['winkelwagen'] as $key=>$val ) {
        $boodschap2 .= "$val x $key<br>";}
    }

    $boodschap = "Naam: " . $_GET["naam"] . '<br>' .  $boodschap2;
    mail("nielbutaye@gmail.com","Uw inkt bestelling", $boodschap);
    echo "Uw gegevens zijn verstuurd";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: After editing with your code  this is the result :Naam: Array
(
   [Zwart 26] => 2
   [Zwart 11] => 3
)

Comment: Updated my answer. The code now has a `foreach` to list each of the orders. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Now it show the order , but it still doensn't show the name I have putted in with the order..

Comment: That is because the name is pulled from the `$_GET` vars. If the 'Naam' field is empty when you click `Verzenden`, the name will not show. I think you'd want to add `$_SESSION['naam'] = $_GET['naam']` to your `// Toevoegen`-block, and then change the line in my answer into `$boodschap = "Naam: " . $_SESSION['naam'] . '<br>' .  $boodschap2;` to have it mailed correctly.